# Using `push` to create a field array in laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I want to add a field array to mongoDB in laravel. I use `push` to create an array field. And I did it the following way:

```
public function addFieldByUser($id)
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        if (empty($product)) {
            abort(404);
        }
        if (!isset($product->image['productC'])) {
            $product->push("image.productC", []);
        }
    }
```

I have successfully added the field `productC` in mongoDB, and here are the results:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6295eb7210b4ec7cb72c9426"),
    "name" : "test",
    "image" : {
        "productA" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "6295eb6c8e88fb54231e66c3",
                "link" : "https://example.com",
                "image" : "dc1c94e421d4ab6a592bcae33ec97345.jpg",
                "externalLink" : true
            }
        ],
        "productB" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "6295eb957cb6f9350f0f0de5",
                "link" : "https://example.com",
                "image" : "1ccd4b1d7601a3beb213eb5b42c5d9bf.jpg",
                "externalLink" : true
            }
        ],
        "productC" : [ 
            []
        ]
    }
}
```

But inside `productC` there is one more sub-array. But my original intention was to add field `productC` as an empty array

I would like to have a result like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6295eb7210b4ec7cb72c9426"),
    "name" : "test",
    "image" : {
        "productA" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "6295eb6c8e88fb54231e66c3",
                "link" : "https://example.com",
                "image" : "dc1c94e421d4ab6a592bcae33ec97345.jpg",
                "externalLink" : true
            }
        ],
        "productB" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "6295eb957cb6f9350f0f0de5",
                "link" : "https://example.com",
                "image" : "1ccd4b1d7601a3beb213eb5b42c5d9bf.jpg",
                "externalLink" : true
            }
        ],
        "productC" : []
    }
}
```

Anyone please give me any suggestions, I'm new to mongoDB so it's really giving me a hard time. Thank you very much

Comment: Because you push an empty array I suppose (`$product->push("image.productC", []);`), what happens if you leave that out or pass `NULL`?

Comment: @geertjanknapen if i `$product->push("image.productC")` it gives error, if pass it = null it is 1 string

Answer (score 0):

Push doesn't make sense here. `push` implies that you have an array that you want to add a value to. But here you just want to initialise an array, so you'll have to use another method.

(Also notably if you use `push` on an eloquent model it'll also save it to the database)

You could do something like `$product->image['productC'] = []`

And then `$product->save()` if you want to save it